# How to fasten file writing in Spark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a code which reads two orc files as two dataframes and joins them into one data frame. My code, then writes this data frame into a file. I tried to know the timing of each step, without writing the output, it takes one minute but when I put in the writing code, it takes around 38 minutes. The data are 5gb, 100 million rows and 50 columns.

The code is:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader, DataFrameWriter
from datetime import datetime

import time

# @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

print("All imports were successful.")

df = spark.read.orc(
    's3://****'
)
print("First dataframe read with headers set to True")
df2 = spark.read.orc(
    's3://****'
)
print("Second dataframe read with headers set to True")

# Obtain columns lists
left_cols = df.columns
right_cols = df2.columns

# Prefix each dataframe's field with "left_" or "right_"
df = df.selectExpr([col + ' as left_' + col for col in left_cols])
df2 = df2.selectExpr([col + ' as right_' + col for col in right_cols])

# Perform join
# df3 = df.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='l.left_c_0' == 'r.right_c_0')

# df3 = df.alias('l').join(df2.alias('r'), on='c_0')

df3 = df.join(
    df2,
    df["left_c_0"] == df2["right_c_0"]
)

print("Dataframes have been joined successfully.")
output_file_path = 's3://****'.format(
    datetime.utcnow()
)

df3.write.orc(
    output_file_path
)
# print("Dataframe has been written to csv.")
job.commit()
```

Just to be clear, when I commented out the `df3.write.orc( output_file_path )`, I could get the script working in < 1 minute.

I am unable to deduce any method for doing the writing task faster. Is there any parallelization that can be done here?

Note, the output files are written in parts.

Comment: Spark is lazy so the input is probably not processed at all when the output is commented out. For starters I'd suggest using spark web ui to figure out the DAG and how much time is spent on different stages.

Comment: I won't be able to access spark web ui simple because I am using AWS Glue, managed Spark.
How can I increase the writing speed is my concern, any idea here?

Answer (score 4):

When you create data frame it is not read from the s3. A data frame is information about from where (and how) to read the data. The same applies when you join the data frames it just created a new data frame which knows that previous two data frames should be processed to get the result.

Finally when you call `df3.write` that is when data for `df1` and `df2` is read and processed. In essence all the application processing (read data from s3, rename columns, join two data frames) happens during the invoking of `df3.write`.
This is why the script finishes in less than 1 second if you remove the last statement `df3.write` (because nothing was actually done).

The real question is how can you make this application faster. It depends on a lot of factors like input data size, the memory and number of processing cores available for the job.